# Find all Combinations of a Given Number of Elements from Two or More Vectors

Tags: r, vector

Using R, I am trying to systematically identify all possible combinations of a given number of elements from two or more vectors.

For example, if I have

```
first <- 10, 20, 30
second <- 1, 2, 3
```

I want to create a matrix of all possible combinations of n=2 elements from each vector, such that I end up with

```
1, 2, 10, 20
1, 2, 20, 30
1, 2, 10, 30
2, 3, 10, 20
2, 3, 20, 30
2, 3, 10, 30
1, 3, 10, 20
1, 3, 20, 30
1, 3, 10, 30
```

I would then like to perform operations on each of these vectors.

Comment: `df <- expand.grid(first, first, second, second); df[df$Var1 < df$Var2 & df$Var3 < df$Var4, ]`

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

---

#### `expand.grid`

Use `expand.grid` to get all the combinations, and subset to those you want:

```
df <- expand.grid(first, first, second, second)
df[df$Var1 < df$Var2 & df$Var3 < df$Var4, ]

##    Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
## 31   10   20    1    2
## 34   10   30    1    2
## 35   20   30    1    2
## 58   10   20    1    3
## 61   10   30    1    3
## 62   20   30    1    3
## 67   10   20    2    3
## 70   10   30    2    3
## 71   20   30    2    3
```

---

#### `combn` and tidyr

Use `combn` to get each set of combinations, arrange into a data.frame, and use `tidyr::expand` with `nesting` to get combinations of each set of columns:

```
library(tidyr)

data.frame(t(rbind(combn(first, 2), combn(second, 2)))) %>% 
    expand(nesting(X1, X2), nesting(X3, X4))

## # A tibble: 9 × 4
##      X1    X2    X3    X4
##   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1    10    20     1     2
## 2    10    20     1     3
## 3    10    20     2     3
## 4    10    30     1     2
## 5    10    30     1     3
## 6    10    30     2     3
## 7    20    30     1     2
## 8    20    30     1     3
## 9    20    30     2     3
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
CJ(first, first, second, second)[V1 < V2 & V3 < V4]
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
#1: 10 20  1  2
#2: 10 20  1  3
#3: 10 20  2  3
#4: 10 30  1  2
#5: 10 30  1  3
#6: 10 30  2  3
#7: 20 30  1  2
#8: 20 30  1  3
#9: 20 30  2  3
```